# How do you convert a Word Document into very simple html in Python?

Tags: python, html, django, ms-word

Every now and then I receive a Word Document that I have to display as a web page.  I'm currently using Django's flatpages to achieve this by grabbing the html content generated by MS Word.  The generated html is quite messy.  Is there a better way that can generate very simple html to solve this issue using Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good solution involves uploading into Google Docs and exporting the html version from it. (There must be an api for that?)

It does so many "clean ups"; [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) down the road can be used to make any further changes, as appropriate. It is the most powerful and elegant html parsing library on the planet.

This is a known standard for Journalist companies.

Comment: But how exactly do you do it from Google Docs? I upload my MSWord doc and choose the convert option - it loses all diagrams

Answer (score 4):

I found this web page: http://www.textfixer.com/html/convert-word-to-html.php

It converts a formated text to **simple** HTML markup, preserving bold, italic, links and paragraphs, but not adding tags for font-sizes and faces. Exactly what I needed to save some time.

Comment: This is freaking amazing! Works exactly as I'd want it to.

Answer (score 3):

My super-simple app [WordOff](http://wordoff.org/) has an [API](http://wordoff.org/api) for cleaning up cruft from Word-exported HTML. You could override the save method of your flatpages model to pipe your HTML through the API the first time it gets saved. Something like this:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

def decruft(html):
    data = urllib.urlencode({'html' : html})
    req = urllib2.Request('http://wordoff.org/api/clean', data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    return response.read()

def save(self, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk: # only de-cruft when content is first added
        self.content = decruft(self.content)
    super(FlatPage, self).save(**kwargs)
```

Comment: WordOff is pretty neat at this kind of thing

Comment: If you want to use wordoff locally you can download the module and use its "superClean" method to get the same result: https://raw.github.com/tomdyson/wordoff/master/wordoff.py

Comment: Hey tomd, WordOff.org expired already though

Answer (score 2):

It depends how much formatting and images you're dealing with. I do one of a couple things:

- **Google Docs**: Probably the closest you'll get to the original formatting and usable HTML.
- **Markdown**: Abandon formatting. Paste it into a plain text editor, run it through Markdown and fix the rest by hand.

Comment: How do I get the HTML from Google Doc? Is it the Download as HTML option?

Comment: +1: Word Doc files are *very* hard to work with.  Many tools will convert them, including Open Office.  Google Docs has a simple API since it's an HTTP web service.

Comment: MS Word -> HTML is just plain evil. I had a client hand me a 95(!) page word document containing hundreds of 'places to see' and say, "It should be easy to enter this into the database." Arrggghh! I did it and billed him $100/hour for the privilege, but I think I undercharged given the amount of pain. The HTML was flat out the worst I have ever had to work with.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Abiword](http://www.abisource.com/)/[wvWare](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/) to convert word document to XHTML and then parse it with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)/[ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm)/etc. to preprocess it if you need. In my experience, Abiword does a pretty good job at converting Word files and produce relatively clean XHTML files.

I should mention that Abiword can be run on the command line, so it's easy to integrate it in an automated process.

Answer (score 2):

Word 2010 has the ability to "save as filtered web page". This will eliminate the overwhelming majority of the HTML that Word inserts.