# word 2 html conversion inside Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

is there any way for a google app engine app to convert a user uploaded docx file to html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the question is really; How can I convert a word document to HTML using Java/Python. and has little to do with google-app-engine itself.

This has been addressed on SO already [for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+word+to+html+python) and [for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+word+to+html+java)

One possible solution would be to use the [Google Apps Document List API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/) to send your file to Google Docs and then retrieve it in another format.

Comment: You are correct to some extent but read on... I have read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596911/how-do-you-convert-a-word-document-into-very-simple-html-in-python) thread. The problem is this: unless I am mistaken, Google Docs API will only let me upload the document to the user's account. This is not what i want. Is there a way to upload the docx to an account associated with my app without any html form popping up asking for username/password? Then I could try exporting the doc to html. Please let me know if i am not clear.

Comment: Yes, you could setup your own Google Docs account and setup [oAuth](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html) token to access your own account and then store it in your app to continually connect to Google docs.