# How to convert .doc files to HTML?

Tags: python, doc

I have a bunch of .doc files (not .docx) and I want to convert them into HTML files.

I tried Python's `docx2html` module too but it only supports .docx files and not doc.

So how can I achieve it?

Comment: It should be fairly simple to just convert all of your .doc files to .docx files with COMs (if you're on Windows)

Comment: @wnnmaw Can you please elaborate exactly how it can be achieved?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python) covers how to convert a .doc to a .pdf, which you should be able to adapt to convert to .doc by replacing ```wdFormatPDF``` with  the appropriate constant from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238158(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: wdFormatDocument97 and 0 value are the ones you're looking for

Comment: Simply convert your doc files to docx. You might wanna have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596911/how-do-you-convert-a-word-document-into-very-simple-html-in-python

Comment: First convert them to docx. Then use this library: https://github.com/mwilliamson/python-mammoth

Comment: Related: [How do you convert a Word Document into very simple html in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1596911/6045800)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by calling LibreOffice's `soffice` into my Python module using `subprocess.call`. With soffice, you can directly convert `doc` to `html`.

But I must inform that with this solution, `outputfile.html` may lose some of the format styles.
In my case, it preserved the fonts face, font size and runs (bold, italic etc.) which were the essentials for me.

```
import subprocess

# Assuming `filename` has already been assigned for input file name
subprocess.call(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'html', filename])
```

This will generate an html document with the same name and in the same directory.

You can then go ahead and re-style the `.html` file with some CSS if it's necessary.