# Python convert word to html

Tags: python, html, ms-word

I'd need to convert a .docx file with colored words into html. I've tried the mammoth library but the colors are lost. How could I achieve my goal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert a Word Document into very simple html in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596911/how-do-you-convert-a-word-document-into-very-simple-html-in-python)

Comment: Is it just one file? Have you tried uploading it to google docs and downloading it as HTML?

Comment: If you only need to convert one file, open the docx document in Word and ```Save As``` as an HTML file.

Comment: No, it's not just one file. The idea is to automate the process.

Comment: give [`mammoth`](https://pypi.org/project/mammoth/) a try

Comment: I tried mammoth but lost the coloring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import win32com.client
doc = win32com.client.GetObject("demo.docx")
doc.SaveAs (FileName="hey.html", FileFormat=8)
doc.Close ()
```

Comment: Actually I'd need to save the html code into a txt file. Would that be possible?

Comment: I don't understand. The OP says docx to Html.
If you need to save an html code to txt,
Use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: I would first need to convert the docx file to an html variable and then deploy that variable into a txt file. Can I do those steps with beautiful soup?

Comment: Yes, indeed. It would have been easier for everyone if you had given some context to your problem.

`soup = BeautifulSoup(open("path_to_hey.html"), "html.parser")`

And then read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694482/converting-html-to-text-with-python)

Comment: The [`FileFormat=`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdsaveformat) parameter also supports other formats including: Word 97 (`0`), Bloated HTML (`8`), MHTML (`9`), Filtered HTML (`10`), DOCX (`16`), PDF (`17`),